# How do I avoid lazyloading placeholders (LQIP) from being cached in Google Images

Tags: javascript, html, css, lazy-loading, lighthouse

I would like to lazyload my images via medium-like `Low Quality Image Placeholder (LQIP)` technic as part of current lighthouse metrics optimisations (particularly `FCP` / `LCP`)

I plan to serve Server-Side-Rendered-HTML with small 10px-wide-images (`LQIPs`) and then on the client I will load original images via javascript (see snippet example).

This approach really helps to boost `LCP` / `FCP`, but my main concern here is **Google's Images Search results** - as my `SSR HTML` contains only small `10px` images, and only Client-side JS will load fullsize `540px` images.

What will google show on its `images` tab - will it cache my LQIPs? How do I avoid them from being cached?

```js
function revealFullsize() {
  document.querySelector(".lqip").classList.add("hide");
  document.querySelector(".original").classList.remove("hide");
}

function loadFullsize(img) {
  document.querySelector(".original").src = "https://lqip.lqip.app/images/open.jpg?w=3000";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.lqip {
  filter: blur(10px);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: opacity .7s;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img class="original hide" onload="revealFullsize()" />
  <img src="https://lqip.lqip.app/images/open.jpg?w=20" class="lqip" onload="loadFullsize(this)" />
  <noscript>
    <img class="original" src="https://lqip.lqip.app/images/open.jpg?w=3000"/>
  </noscript>
</div>
```

Comment: Google has a page that may be useful [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/prevent-images-on-your-page). Assuming you can detect the difference between a low/normal quality image URL using regex, their suggested method should work.

Comment: @DBS do you know any other options? I see medium doesnt have anything in their robots txt, though the images are not being cached